# Safari does not download files automatically

Tags: macos, browser-addons, safari

The expected behaviour of Safari when clicking on a, for example, .torrent file, is that it is downloaded.

Only this does not happen any more, it just shows a dark, blank page

[image: safari]

The only way to download the .torrent file is to right click the link to it and select "Download linked file to 'Downloads'".

It should probably be worth noting that these problems started when I added GreaseKit to Safari, but I would very much like to keep GreaseKit enabled. Is there some other way to fix Safari?

Comment: What user scripts are you using?

Comment: SOFU infinite-scroll-on-answers, and two to style google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in GreaseKit.

Please note, that Greasekit hasn't been updated in quite a while.

> ### GreaseKit Changes
>
> #### 1.7 (2008-09-22)
>
> ```
> Fixed installation problem.
> Added GM_addStyle and GM_log.
> Moved "GreaseKit" menu to left of the "Window" menu.
> And these modification is based on Jiang Jiang's patch.
> ```

The last update is over two years old, so try contacting the programmer and see if you can get it fixed.

Check out this [GreseKit Users post](http://groups.google.com/group/greasekit-users/browse_thread/thread/7f27fd9aa1cb12c8), where they were reporting that there has been some issues with Safari & Leopard..

Also consider that the Greasemonkey forums are not being monitored, or administrated very well: They're full of spam.

So, in my opinion, see if you can get your functionality in a different way.  If you rely on technology that isn't being maintained, it'll eventually break and you'll be stuck scrambling around to find a solution in a hurry.

Comment: I am actually using a recent SVN build of it, which is less than 2 years old.

Comment: But yes, I think I will contact someone else about it...