# Safari downloads failure on OS X

Tags: macos, safari

I had Speed Downloader installed a while ago and it seems I have deleted it improperly since almost all downloads in safari look exactly like in this question here - [Safari does not download files automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/53858/safari-does-not-download-files-automatically)

Is there a way to restore or reset downloading settings in Safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safari does not download files automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/53858/safari-does-not-download-files-automatically)

Comment: Similar, but not a dupe, imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the remnant folder of the extension that was buried somewhere, Spotlight managed to find it, and voilà, DLs work.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset Safari by clicking on `Safari > Reset Safari`. This should also reset the download settings.

You can also deselect the things you don't want to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Speed download has a Safari plugin.
Are you sure you disabled or uninstalled it?

[image]